# Save Datetime in variable to reflect in HTML Django/python

Tags: python, django, function, datetime

I need to know how to save the date when a function was triggered. My function triggers a logic to create a report with calculations and new data every hour. My idea was to create a function that save the date this way:

```
def last_modify(request):
    x = []
    last_mod = str(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m %H:%M"))
    context = {
        'date': last_mod
    }
    x.append(context)
    render(request, 'news-dashboard.html', context)
```

Not sure if I'm on the right path, and if I have to reflect it in the html template Last date modified: {{ date }} this is for the users to know when was the report last updated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried to run the above? Worth noting that the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have tried, but is not reflecting in the html side...

Comment: Your function isn't returning the result of `render`. How do you call this function? Is it a view for a particular URL? This doesn't seem right since the only dynamic thing in the template will be the date. What's the variable `x` for?

Comment: to save the date into x

Comment: what is variable  {{ date }}  rendering in your template?